# The given key was not present in the dictionary when using text inputs for ajax/json calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, dictionary, get

Hey guys I ran into an unfamiliar issue and am curious if anybody knows a solution for it.  I would like to start by saying thank you in advance for taking the time to read.  So my problem is that when I am making a ajax/json call to my web api it works fine if it is just clicking a button.  If the call is used in a form and gets values from input fields it fails and gives me the error "The given key was not present in the dictionary".

This works fine to get all users:

```
$(function () {
            var $users = $("#users");
            $("button[name='getAllUsers']").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: "/api/Users",
                    contentType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $users.html("");
                        $users.append("<tr><td><b>First Name</b></td><td><b>Last Name</b></td><td><b>Email</b></td></tr>");
                        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                            $users.append("<tr><td>" + item.FirstName + "</td>" +
                                                  "<td>" + item.LastName + "</td>" +
                                                  "<td>" + item.Email + "</td>");
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });

<table id="users"></table>
<button name="getAllUsers">Get Users</button>
```

And this does not work when I try to get a single user by id:

```
$(function () {
            var $users = $("#users");
            $("#getForm").submit(function (event) {
                var id = $('#getuserId').val();
                $.getJSON('/api/Users' + id)
               .done(function (data) {
                   $users.html("");
                   $users.append("<tr><td><b>First Name</b></td><td><b>Last Name</b></td><td><b>Email</b></td></tr>");
                   $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                       $users.append("<tr><td>" + item.FirstName + "</td>" +
                                             "<td>" + item.LastName + "</td>" +
                                             "<td>" + item.Email + "</td>");
                   });
               });
               });
            });

<form action="/api/Users" id="getForm">
                <input type="text" name="getuserId" placeholder="User ID">
                <input type="submit" value="Get User">
            </form>
<table id="users"></table>
```

Any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a trailing slash in your URI:

```
$.getJSON('/api/Users' + id)
```

For the id `50` would make a GET request to: `/api/Users50`. It should be:

```
$.getJSON('/api/Users/' + id)
```

Which would result in `api/Users/50`.

Comment: I tried this one too and am still getting the same error.  First time encountering this type of error lol.  I am trying to figure out if it is in the json call or the .net api methods atm.